# Create Empty Array Variable With React Functional Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How do I create/set an empty array as a variable in React function component?

I'm trying to create animations with Greensock and can individually set references but wanted to do things cleaner. I tried setting with `let cardRef[] = useRef();` but that throws an error.

Here's the [codpen](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/zYOdZYE) for more reference.

Comment: *Edit Note*: From `Functional` to [Function](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) component.

Comment: What'd be the purpose of the array? Would it be just one-time read-only array? Or should it be part of the state?

Comment: a ref ought to point to a single element. You're trying to point it to three.

Comment: How do you plan on using this array? Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help out... you can create an "empty array variable" like this: `let arr = new Array(n);` or like `let arr = Array(n);` or like `let arr = [...Array(n).keys()];` It all depends what you are trying to do.... Need more info.

Comment: @sungmkim functional component is acceptable term, been used all over the tutorials, blogs and youtube.

Comment: OP is trying to store references of divs in an array of cardRef based on example link provided. Usage in example link is wrong however

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't take credit for this (Credit goes to @OSUblake from GSAP Community) but the solution was `let cardRef = useRef([]);` .

Basically, with the array ref, I can target my items using `cardRef.current[x]`.

This dries my code up a bit, as GSAP's `staggerFrom` method requires an array.

See updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/zYOdZYE) to see how reference was used.